# How messages are produced from Java Api. Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am doing my first tests with Kafka and Java Api

Below I detail the steps I am following, it is a new world for me and I do not know if I am missing a step, but I do not take it.

The first thing I think is a zookeeper and a kafka with a docker, I enter kafka and execute commands and it is correct

// docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.6"
services:
zk-svc:
 image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
 ports:
  - "2181:2181"
 restart: always
kafka-svc:
 image: wurstmeister/kafka
 depends_on:
  - zk-svc
 ports:
  - "9092:9092"
 restart: always

 environment:
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.1.147
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zk-svc:2181
```

I create a topic called "test"

// CREATE TOPIC

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

I look at the ip of my container

// GET IP CONTAINER

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' kafka-zk_zk-svc_1
```

And finally I apply the data of my topic and ip of my container, in the java class that produces messages

// JAVA CLASS

```
public class Producers {
public static String brokerList = "172.21.0.3:9092";
public static String topic = "test";

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokerList);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, "com.kafka.api.producer.SimplePartitioner");

    Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

    for (int id = 0; id < 5000; id++) {
        String key = String.format("key[%d]", id);
        String message = String.format("message[%d]", id);
        System.out.println("Sending message with: " + key);
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, key, message));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    producer.flush();
    producer.close();
}
}
```

According to the java console it seems that he is sending well:

// java console

```
Sending message with: key[0]
Sending message with: key[1]
Sending message with: key[2]
...
```

I create a consumer:

// CREATE CONSUMER

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

In the consumer nothing comes to me. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.
Does anyone see if any step is wrong or I am missing one?

Comment: Why do you have the different values in `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` and the `brokerList` config?

Comment: daniu It was that, thank you very much. ( brokerList = "192.168.1.147:9092";)